# How can i know when i can execute what functions of wordpress?

Tags: conditional-tags, core

I like to do a bunch of stuff only on homepage and archive pages

i am working with the genesis framework (not really matters i guess)

```
if( is_singular() ) {
    wp_die('functions.php');
}

add_action( 'init', function() {

    if( is_singular() ) {
        wp_die('init');
    }

});

add_action( 'genesis_before', function() {

    if( is_singular() ) {
        wp_die('genesis_before');
    }

});
```

only the 3rd get executed, i looking for some reference about that i run into some issues like that before. How do get get to know the wordpress scructure better without digging into the source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install my plugin [T5 WP Load Order](https://gist.github.com/4055044). You get a long detailed list with all available hooks, files, constants, classes, functions and global variables – ordered by first appearance.

Whenever you’re in doubt create such a list for the page you are working on, and look up what you need.